# Radio button inside Remote view

Tags: android, animation, radio-button, remoteview

I have a radio button inside the remote view of android. Upon clicking the layout of the radio button, it is getting selected but no animation or ripple effect is being shown. How to show the default check animation.

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_dolby_level1"
    style="@style/tile_preset_effect_radio_button" />
```

this is the style

```
<style name="tile_preset_effect_radio_button" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">24dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">false</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">false</item>
</style>
```

and this is how I am checking the radio button

```
mRemoteViews.setBoolean(getDolbyTileRadioId(mDolbyValue), "setChecked", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `RadioButton` in a `RemoteViews`. `RemoteViews` is limited to support some layouts and widgets:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews

An important point is that descendants of supporting classes are not supported.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, There was a necessity that it was must to have it inside remote view. Now, is there any solution for the animation.

Comment: I guess there is no way :-(

Comment: Is there any way I can call the performClick method of radio button from remote view?

Comment: Unfortunately every attempts I did before to do sth more than mentioned functionalities by the android doc, failed, even tricky ones. So, I think nothing more than what the above link said is possible.